# Group an array with dynamic key values?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I  have JSON array values as given below,

```
{
  "test_details": [
    {
      "test_id": "001",
      "test_name": "Blood Test",
      "group_name": "Group 1",
      "package_details": [
        {
          "package_name": "master health checkup",
          "package_id": "1"
        },
        {
          "package_name": "special camp package",
          "package_id": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "test_id": "002",
      "test_name": "haemoglobin",
      "group_name": "Group 2",
      "package_details": [
        {
          "package_name": "master health checkup",
          "package_id": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "test_id": "003",
      "test_name": "creatine test",
      "group_name": "Group 2",
      "package_name": null
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above JSON, I want to group the values by the key `package_name`, which means I want to order the test list against the package name.

I have tried several array group by functions but for a dynamic key `package_name`, it is not working.

My final output JSON would be:

```
{
  "test_details": {
    "master health checkup": [
      {
        "test_id": "001",
        "test_name": "Blood Test",
        "group_name": "Group 1",
        "package_details": [
          {
            "package_name": "master health checkup",
            "package_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "special camp package",
            "package_id": "2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test_id": "002",
        "test_name": "haemoglobin",
        "group_name": "Group 2",
        "package_details": [
          {
            "package_name": "master health checkup",
            "package_id": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "special camp package": [
      {
        "test_id": "001",
        "test_name": "Blood Test",
        "group_name": "Group 1",
        "package_details": [
          {
            "package_name": "master health checkup",
            "package_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "package_name": "special camp package",
            "package_id": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here you can see the **master health checkup** have 2 tests and under and same as **special camp package** have 1 test. how to achieve this? how to apply array group by when the array key is dynamic?

Comment: Could you put an example of your desire output there?

Comment: @EmilioGort it was already there, but another editor deleted it for some reason. I put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decoding the JSON, iterate the `test_details`. If a test has a `package_details` property, then iterate that and assign the test to your result array using each package name as the key.

```
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->test_details as $test) {
    if (isset($test->package_details)) {
        foreach ($test->package_details as $package) {
            $result['test_details'][$package->package_name][] = $test;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```